How does conservation of energy work with time dilation?
According to special relativity time will appear to have slowed down for an observer $B$ travelling at a uniform speed when observed by an observer $A$ (say 1s for $B$ equals 2s for A). If that is true then, let's say there's a bulb connected to a battery in B's spaceship (who is travelling) this bulb can glow for say $t$ time which is say $2t$ for $A$ therefore the bulb will glow longer for $A$ than for $B$? Is this true? can we get a light bulb to last longer by moving it at a high speed? how does conservation of energy work with time dilatation?

Different frames of reference will observe different values of energy (even in calssical physics this is true, think $\frac{1}{2}m v^2$ in various frames). But they will agree within their frame, that the four-momentum vector is conserved

A similar situation is if B sends out two particles each with energy $E$ in opposite directions. It isn't difficult to show that according to A they will both have energy $2E.$

You can take inspiration from electromagnetism.In electromagnetism depending on the frame of reference you can have E and B , only B or only E fields.However the electromagnetic tensor(which is invariant under Lorentz transformation)remains the same.

Energy is proportional to power multiplied by time. For an observer that sees the light bulb as moving, it is emitting light at a lower power for a longer duration, but the total energy used up $(\text{Watts} \times \text{seconds})$ is the same from all reference frames, by the time the battery is exhausted. To the observer moving with the light bulb, the brightness appears normal. An observer who sees the light bulb moving in a circle around him will see the light bulb's brightness diminished by a factor of gamma and brighter or dimmer if the bulb is moving towards them or away from them, respectively, in accordance with the relativistic Doppler factor.
If we were to place a series of detectors in a huge sphere around the stationary light bulb and capture all ($n$) emitted photons that are emitted during the lifetime of the battery, the total captured energy would be $n h f$ where $h$ is the Planck constant, and $f$ is the frequency of the emitted light. If the light bulb is moving relative to the detectors, some of the detectors that see the bulb as coming towards them will see the frequency of the photons blue-shifted to a higher energy, and some of the detectors that see the bulb as going away from them will see the photons red-shifted to a lower frequency and a lower energy. The total number of photons emitted by the time the battery is exhausted is the same whether the bulb is stationary or moving according to the observers, and when all the photons are summed with their respective blue-shifted or red-shifted energies, the total energy captured by the detectors is the same whether the bulb is stationary or moving relative to them.

Just to clarify, the light will appear dimmed to the observer at rest because of the Doppler effect? and this will hold true for sound (i.e. volume of the sound will be lesser) or other phenomenon as well?

This is not true: "the total energy used up $(\text{Watts} \times \text{seconds})$ is the same from all reference frames". Energy is relative.

@md2perpe let's say if we get a satellite to go around a planet close to a speed necessary for $\gamma = 2$. You are saying that the bulb inside that satellite will glow at the same intensity and 2 times longer than it would have normally? wouldn't this create extra energy in the system which is impossible?

@manik. Not necessarily with the same intensity, nor with the same frequency distribution. But it will give off the double amount of energy. According to A the battery contains the double energy than according to B. We cannot create energy by accelerating a battery, because also the energy has inertia. To accelerate energy $E$ to $\gamma=2$ we have to add energy $E$ to get a total energy $2E.$

Ignoring all the Doppler shifting concerns etc., the bulb just glows at a lower intensity.
That is, everyone agrees that in this thing’s rest frame, it is a 100 watt light bulb, it is consuming 100 watts and pouring out some number of lumens. But in a reference frame moving relative with $\gamma =2$, it appears to consume 50 watts, produce about half the lumens, the light all appears to be emitted in the direction that it is going (“relativistic beaming”,) and the light so beamed is generally going to shift wavelengths.

Are you saying that the light will be dimmer regardless of the Doppler effect?

We have $\gamma=2.$ This doesn't only mean that when time $t$ passes at the origin of the B frame, time $2t$ passes in the A frame; it also means that if the battery contains energy $E$ according to B, then the battery contains energy $2E$ according to A. Thus the bulb can send out double the energy.
Can we then just produce energy by accelerating a battery and a bulb to get double the energy out? No. Energy has inertia and it requires energy to accelerate energy. So we do not only need to put in energy to accelerate the massive battery and the bulb, but also to accelerate the energy in the battery. The extra amount of energy we need to put in is $E,$ the extra amount of energy that we will then get out of the battery.
EDIT
Energy is relative. If the energy and momentum (in the direction of movement) are $E_B$ and $p_B$ in the B frame, then in the A frame they are
$E_A = \gamma(E_B + p_B v)$ and $p_A = \gamma(p_B + E_B v/c^2).$
In our case $\gamma=2$ and $p_B=0$ for the battery, so $E_A=2E_B,$ i.e. according to A the energy in the battery is twice the energy according to B.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4679288/168433

As per the other answers the total emitted energy will be the same, the only difference is that for the observer at rest the light is dimmer and lasts longer. Are you saying that this is not the case?

@Manik. Correct, I do not agree with the other answer.

There is no issue here. Everything associated with the spaceship will appear to happen more slowly in the stationary frame. For example, if the bulb emits n photons per second in the frame of the spaceship, it will emit n/2 photons per second in the stationary frame, so there is consistency overall in terms of the total number of photons emitted.

Let's say a box moves at speed 0.87 c along the equator of the earth. Inside the box there are a light bulb, a light sensor, and a battery that powers the bulb.
When the battery is empty, a truck brings a new one, takes old battery back, and also takes all the energy that was in the old battery back to a warehouse at rest on earth. The energy is sucked, as heat energy, out of the walls that absorbed the light that the bulb produced.
Now it's easy to calculate that half the power is needed to keep the light sensor inside the moving box at some reading, compared to if the box was at rest relative to earth.
Truck uses no energy, it just accelerates a mass and decelerates the same amount of mass. And battery change frequency is halved.

Momentum is only conserved in four dimensions.
Acceleration in N Dimensions is always rotation in N + 1 dimensions. In a dark room, a candle on the edge of a rotating platter appears to be accelerating left and right, left and right, in one dimension. But a more complete 2D view from above reveals rotation.
You only get time dilation when a mass accelerates. When you see something accelerated, the frequency of the onboard  light is reduced. That lower energy is exactly balanced by the energy added to the three dimensional momentum as it accelerates.
When you accelerate an object, you're rotating its extent (4-momentum vector) away from the time direction (elapsed time) and increasing its extent in a space direction.

Several claims here are untrue. 'You only get time dilation when a mass accelerates' -> according to special relativity, this happens at constant relative speeds.
'Acceleration in N dimension is always rotation in N+1 dimensions' -> not sure what this means or the relevance to the subject.

@Frotaur >"'You only get time dilation when a mass accelerates' ->this happens at constant relative speeds." == only after acceleration has occurred == "'Acceleration in N dimension is always rotation in N+1 dimensions' -> not sure what this means" == it means that acceleration is angular momentum. == "or the relevance to the subject' == Angular momentum is conserved.
